# When you click the button in the sidebar, execute the previously selected submenu function

Tags: google-apps-script

What I need to achieve is the following, generate a menu, which adds Submenus and its function that I define in FnList and as long as the function exists, but without repeating the submenu. Each new item will be added to the corresponding submenu, for which I have this script that does work.

```
var FnList = [
  { submenu: ' DATOS', funcion: 'DESCARGA' },
  { submenu: '⚙️ CONFIGURACION', funcion: 'FORMATO' },
  { submenu: '⚙️ CONFIGURACION', funcion: 'AJUSTAR' },
  { submenu: '⚙️ CONFIGURACION', funcion: 'DIMENSIONES' }
];

function MENU() {
  var creados = {}; //
  for (var i = 0; i < FnList.length; i++) {
    var menuItem = FnList[i];
    var submenuName = menuItem.submenu;
    var funcion = menuItem.funcion;
    if (typeof this[funcion] === 'function') {
      if (!creados[submenuName]) { creados[submenuName] = UI.createMenu(submenuName); }
      creados[submenuName].addItem(funcion, SIDEBAR);
    }
  }
  for (var submenuName in creados) { menu.addSubMenu(creados[submenuName]); }
  menu.addToUi();
}
```

I want the functions of each submenu to execute a SIDEBAR which generates a button for each existing worksheet with its corresponding name.

```
function SIDEBAR(submenuSeleccionado) {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput().setTitle('SELECCION');
  var buttonHtml = '<ul>';
  for (var i = 0; i < Hojas.length; i++) {
    var hoja = Hojas[i];
    var nombreHoja = hoja.getName();
    buttonHtml += `<div class="OBJETOS"><button type="button" class="BOTON" onclick="${submenuSeleccionado}">${nombreHoja}</button></div>`;
  }
  buttonHtml += '</ul>';
  buttonHtml = BaseHtml + buttonHtml;
  html.append(buttonHtml);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

This uses an html style for the buttons that comes from a var called BaseHtml

```
var BaseHtml = 
    <body>
          <div class = "OBJETOS" >
            <button type="button" class= "BOTON" 
            value="BOTONi" onclick=" FUNCIONSUBMENU; CARGANDO();" > nombredelahoja </button>
          </div>
          <div style="display: block; "id = "PREPARANDO" class="ANIMACION" >
            <p> Selecciona la hoja.</p>
          </div>
          <div style="display: none; "id = "GENERANDO" class="ANIMACION" >
            <p> Aplicando cambios.</p>
            <i class="fa fa-gear fa-spin"></i>
          </div>
          <div style="display: none;" id="FINALIZADO" class="ANIMACION">
            <h3> Proceso terminado. </h3>
            <i class="fa fa-solid fa-file-arrow-down fa-fade"></i>
          </div>
        <script>

          function CARGANDO() {
            document.getElementById("PREPARANDO").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("GENERANDO").style.display = "block"
            document.getElementById("FINALIZADO").style.display = "none";
            }

          function COMPLETE() {
            document.getElementById("GENERANDO").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("FINALIZADO").style.display = "block";
        </script>
      </body>
```

The summary of what I'm looking for is the following

Generate a Menu with Submenus based on FnList, when clicking on the Submenu for example: SETTINGS I want the SIDEBAR function to be executed and the buttons are displayed, one for each worksheet. Now when you click on any button, for example: Sheet01

I want the function from the SETTINGS submenu to be executed on that sheet.

Comment: What is `var BaseHtml = <body>,,,`? And, I think that in your function `MENU()`, it seems that `menu` is not declared. By this, I'm worried that an error will occur. But, you say `this script that does work.`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script. How about this? And, can I ask you about the details of `I want the function from the SETTINGS submenu to be executed on that sheet.`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.